# How do I change the orientation and layout of buttons for Android Menu?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-menu

I want to change how the items are oriented in the menu of my app. Currently I have two buttons with one stacked on the other. How can I place it side by side?

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" > 
    <item 
         android:id="@+id/menu_settings" 
         android:orderInCategory="100"
         android:title="@string/menu_settings" 
         android:actionLayout="@layout/main"/> 
    <item 
         android:id="@+id/menu_help" 
         android:title="@string/menu_help" 
         android:actionLayout="@layout/main"/> 
</menu>
```

Sorry for poor formatting, I am new to stack overflow.

Comment: Posting the xml file would help.

Comment: I have added the XML file.

Comment: what does your `main` layout file look like? Its being used as the action view. Did you try to work around with that?

Comment: Yes I just added that line thinking it will get the layout info from the main.xml file to fit the screen and everything. It didnt do much. I am new to programming so I I have no idea what's happening.

Comment: Did you try Oleksiy's answer?

Answer (score 0):

Try something like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:id="@+id/item1"
      android:icon="@drawable/item1icon"
      android:title="@string/itemString"
      android:showAsAction="ifRoom"/>
    <item android:id="@+id/help"
      android:icon="@drawable/ic_help"
      android:title="@string/help" />
</menu>
```

It's weird that your buttons are stacked on top of each other. You should post your XML

Comment: `<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

        <item
            android:id="@+id/menu_settings"
            android:orderInCategory="100"
            android:title="@string/menu_settings" android:actionLayout="@layout/main"/>
        <item
            android:id="@+id/menu_help"
            android:title="@string/menu_help" android:actionLayout="@layout/main"/>

</menu>`

Sorry for poor formatting, I am new to stack overflow.

Comment: try to remove android:actionLayout and android:orderInCategory="100"